# Replace the pattern a certain number of times per line, using sed

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I am trying to find out how to replace a pattern a certain number of times using `sed`.

I found that `sed` with `g` flag replaces all occurences, w/o 1 time, with specified number replace this occurence, `g3` greater/equal 3.

But how to replace pattern from some section or smaller than some number?

e.g. input, single line contains card number and i want to hash part of it

```
1234 1234 1234 1234  
1234 1234 1234 1234
1234 1234 1234 1234
1234 1234 1234 1234
```

Commands:

```
$ sed "s/[0-9]\\{4\\}/\\*\\*\\*\\*/g"
**** **** **** ****
$ sed "s/[0-9]\\{4\\}/\\*\\*\\*\\*/g3"
1234 1234 **** ****
$ sed "s/[0-9]\\{4\\}/\\*\\*\\*\\*/2"
**** 1234 **** ****
```

I am looking for way to replace with hash specific occurrence of pattern e.g. 1-3 or <3. For more occurrence of pattern in each line can be 5-10 or something else

Comment: From `ìnfo sed`: *"     Note: the POSIX standard does not specify what should happen when
     you mix the 'g' and NUMBER modifiers, and currently there is no
     widely agreed upon meaning across 'sed' implementations.  For GNU
     'sed', the interaction is defined to be: ignore matches before the
     NUMBERth, and then match and replace all matches from the NUMBERth
     on."* - so you should not really use that feature you describe anyway as it is not standardized and will give you portability issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU `sed`, Yes, has that option to replace all `g` occuraces of a patten or from Xth occurrence to all after that `gX`,  but you can use these two extensions to achieve what you want to replace only **first** Y occuraces like below to replace first 3 occuraces of PATTERN.

```
sed -E 's/PATTERN/TEMP-REPLACE/g4; s/PATTERN/REPLACE/g; s/TEMP-REPLACE/PATYERN/g' infile.txt
```

Also as non-GNU solution, you can have Y `sed` parts to replace Y times of a PATTERN like below,

```
sed -E -e 's/PATTERN/REPLACE/' -e 's/PATTERN/REPLACE/' -e 's/PATTERN/REPLACE/'
```

---

**Updated answer as question revised**

You could use `awk` for it with defining two control flag for START and END and do like below:

```
awk -v START=1 -v END=5 '{for (i=START;i<=END;i++) gsub(/PATTERN/,"****",$i)}1' infile.txt
```

please note that by default `awk` considering to read file delimited by  *tab* or *space*, if yours is different or you want to tell awk it's for example is `,`, you can set with its `-F','` option.